# Why is Chrome cutting off text in my CSS3 multi-column layout?

Tags: google-chrome, css

I am using CSS multi-column layout to display text. The layout displays correctly in Firefox. Chrome, however, has a bug that *cuts/clips off the tops and bottoms of text characters*. Why is this happening? How can I make it work in Chrome?

Here is a screenshot of the problem:

[image: Screenshot showing the bug in Chrome, with text getting cut off]

```css
.multicolumn {
  max-width: 25em;
  columns: 3;
  margin: 0;
  font: 1.2em/.9 sans-serif;
}

.multicolumn p {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="multicolumn">
  <p>hydrolytically hypabyssally hypogyny hyponymy mystifyingly karyotypically bathymetrically cloyingly</p>
</div>
```

Finally, here is the webpage where I'm trying to get this to work: [http://www.vcn.bc.ca/~dugan/css3/newhtml.html](http://www.vcn.bc.ca/%7Edugan/css3/newhtml.html)

Comment: Breaks in Safari on Windows as well (in the same way).

Comment: Could this be a web font issue? I've seen other strange behavior for chrome + web fonts, that seem to be related to how chrome calculate line heights etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems to show all the text if you set a line height of 1.5 on the p rule in dugan.css.  There still seems to be a defect in exactly how Chrome balances the columns, you may need to put an empty paragraph in or add some padding on the last paragraph or something.

Answer (score 39):

Adjusting line-height (or font-size, as recommended elsewhere) might remove Chrome's clipping bug, but only accidentally. If you want to avoid it programmatically, the only working solution by now is:

```
.multicolumn p {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

You might expand this to all child elements of the multicolumn container, but probably you will need to add `width: 100%;` at some point. For more info, read the discussion at
http://www.symphonious.net/2010/12/30/controlling-wrapping-in-css3-columns/ 
and
http://zomigi.com/blog/deal-breaker-problems-with-css3-multi-columns/.

Furthermore, if the inline-block workaround does not help, the cause for cutting off text bits can consist of a recursive application of multi-column design. I observed this in a more complex scenario than the above where a remote parent of a multi-column text container had its own column layout. Removing the column-count from the top-level container fixed the column-break problems.

Comment: This is the best answer for this problem.

Comment: Kinda sucks that your 2013 answer still seems to be the most appropriate, but `display: inline-block;` + `width: 100%;` does seem to deal with my quick and dirty prototype issue.

Answer (score 8):

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Multiple-column_Layout#setting_break-inside) has example to solve this issue.

```
.column-item {
  break-inside: avoid;
  page-break-inside: avoid;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

```
body{ 
    -webkit-column-break-inside:avoid;
}
```

Comment: This fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 2):

Set `break-inside: avoid` on the element(s) being cut off.

This works not just for text, but for divs, etc.

Answer (score 1):

In certain situations, I've seen padding and margins in the columnized content cause this problem.  Try:

```
.columnized-content { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
```

Comment: Additionally, you can try  {box-sizing: border-box;} if you wish to keep the padding

Answer (score 0):

It is more like a bug in chrome i guess.In my case, **clear: both** was set to the box. unsetting it and giving box-sizing:border-box; solved it for me.