# How to display an unordered list in two columns?

Tags: html, css, html-lists, css-multicolumn-layout

With the following HTML, what is the easiest method to display the list as two columns?

```
<ul>
    <li>A</li>
    <li>B</li>
    <li>C</li>
    <li>D</li>
    <li>E</li>
</ul>
```

Desired display:

```
A B
C D
E
```

The solution needs to work with Internet Explorer.

Comment: Here's a live example of how to easily do it in jquery: jsfiddle.net/EebVF/5 Using this jquery plugin: github.com/fzondlo/jquery-columns - I like this better than with CSS because with the CSS solution not everything aligns vertically to the top.

Answer (score 546, accepted):

### Modern Browsers

leverage the css3 columns module to support what you are looking for.

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_columns.asp

**CSS:**

```
ul {
  columns: 2;
  -webkit-columns: 2;
  -moz-columns: 2;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/HP85j/8/

### Legacy Browsers

Unfortunately for IE support you will need a code solution that involves JavaScript and dom manipulation. This means that anytime the contents of the list changes you will need to perform the operation for reordering the list into columns and reprinting. The solution below uses jQuery for brevity.

http://jsfiddle.net/HP85j/19/

**HTML:**

```
<div>
    <ul class="columns" data-columns="2">
        <li>A</li>
        <li>B</li>
        <li>C</li>
        <li>D</li>
        <li>E</li>
        <li>F</li>
        <li>G</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
(function($){
    var initialContainer = $('.columns'),
        columnItems = $('.columns li'),
        columns = null,
        column = 1; // account for initial column
    function updateColumns(){
        column = 0;
        columnItems.each(function(idx, el){
            if (idx !== 0 && idx > (columnItems.length / columns.length) + (column * idx)){
                column += 1;
            }
            $(columns.get(column)).append(el);
        });
    }
    function setupColumns(){
        columnItems.detach();
        while (column++ < initialContainer.data('columns')){
            initialContainer.clone().insertBefore(initialContainer);
            column++;
        }
        columns = $('.columns');
    }

    $(function(){
        setupColumns();
        updateColumns();
    });
})(jQuery);
```

**CSS:**

```
.columns{
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    margin-right: 20px;
}
```

**EDIT:**

As pointed out below this will order the columns as follows:

```
A  E
B  F
C  G
D
```

while the OP asked for a variant matching the following:

```
A  B
C  D
E  F
G
```

To accomplish the variant you simply change the code to the following:

```
function updateColumns(){
    column = 0;
    columnItems.each(function(idx, el){
        if (column > columns.length){
            column = 0;
        }
        $(columns.get(column)).append(el);
        column += 1;
    });
}
```

Comment: You're not displaying the items in the correct order:
http://jsfiddle.net/HP85j/258/
For example, the desired display in the first line is `A B` (the second element should be appended on the right), but in your examples is `A E`.

Comment: Great work, although the logic is flawed if there are more than 2 columns, I've created the fix here: http://jsfiddle.net/HP85j/393/

Comment: the bullets are missing

Comment: interestingly, this doesn't print. :\  ... also you need to re-add list-style. At least in Chrome.

Comment: It's probably more likely to want the list to fill down column 1 before column 2. It might be easier to simply reorder the items of the list so it appears that they filled across before down. Of course that may require redoing if the list changes. Anyway, Gabriel's CSS answer was just what I needed, thank you!

Comment: Just a late update, I believe the first option will now work in modern IE browsers.

Comment: How do you prevent items from cutting off in the middle when they roll over to the next column? [Like this](http://i.imgur.com/I7Jx08L.png)

Comment: Nevermind, found it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3322891/why-is-chrome-cutting-off-text-in-my-css3-multi-column-layout

Comment: Legacy means for columns below IE10: https://caniuse.com/#feat=multicolumn So hopefully nowadays nobody has to build html working is such old browsers

Comment: Doesn't display bullets on the second column

Comment: The comments mentionning the order is not the one requested in the question are not relevant. OP chose to use a <ul> element, the order shouldn't be important...

Comment: Worked for me in chrome and firefox.

Answer (score 102):

I was looking at @jaider's solution which worked but I'm offering a slightly different approach that I think is more easy to work with and which I've seen to be good across browsers.

```
ul{
    list-style-type: disc;
    -webkit-columns: 2;
    -moz-columns: 2;
    columns: 2;
    list-style-position: inside;//this is important addition
}
```

By default un-ordered list display the bullet position outside but then in some browsers it would cause some display problems based on the browser's way of laying out your website.

To get it to display in the format:

```
A B
C D
E
```

etc. use the following:

```
ul li{
    float: left;
    width: 50%;//helps to determine number of columns, for instance 33.3% displays 3 columns
}
ul{
    list-style-type: disc;
}
```

This should solve all your problems with displaying columns. All the best and thanks @jaider as your response helped to guide me to discover this.

Comment: There is a problem with this method.  It works great for displaying very short (1 character in this example) list items.  Create a list with longer descriptions and the second column overlaps the first, as well as runs out of the ul container.

Comment: I tweaked this slightly by changing float: left to display: inline-block for li elements, other than that this worked wonders for me.

Answer (score 47):

I tried posting this as a comment, but couldn't get the columns to display right (as per your question).

You are asking for:

A B

C D

E

... but the answer accepted as the solution will return:

A D

B E

C

... so either the answer is incorrect or the question is.

A very simple solution would be to set the width of your `<ul>` and then float and set the width of your `<li>` items like so

```
<ul>
    <li>A</li>
    <li>B</li>
    <li>C</li>
    <li>D</li>
    <li>E</li>
</ul>

ul{
    width:210px;
}
li{
    background:green;
    float:left;
    height:100px;
    margin:0 10px 10px 0;
    width:100px;
}
li:nth-child(even){
    margin-right:0;
}
```

Example here http://jsfiddle.net/Jayx/Qbz9S/1/

If your question is wrong, then the previous answers apply (with a JS fix for lacking IE support).

Comment: @Gabriel your solution and the behavior is good and as expected, so I'm not trying to knock your answer hey ... I just think that the question might have been misinterpreted ... either way - the question has been answered no matter which is the correct question :D

Answer (score 28):

Now days, for the expected result, `display:grid;` would do *(be the easiest ?)*:

```css
ul {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>A</li>
  <li>B</li>
  <li>C</li>
  <li>D</li>
  <li>E</li>
</ul>
```

you can also get the columns shrinking on the left and able to have different width:

```css
ul {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, auto);
  justify-content: start;
}

li {
  margin-left: 1em;
  border: solid 1px;/*see me */
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>A</li>
  <li>B</li>
  <li>C 123456</li>
  <li>D</li>
  <li>E</li>
</ul>
```

**edit**
To draw columns afters columns, there is 2 options ***(unlike column CSS, each column can have its own width)*** .

- set the numbers of row within the `grid-template-rows` `rule and grid-auto-flow`

```css
ul {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(0em, max-content));
  grid-template-rows: repeat(5, 1fr);/* 5 rows */
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 1em;
  gap: 5px
}

li {
  background: silver;
  padding: 0.15em;
  margin: 0;
}

li::first-letter {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>A</li>
  <li>B</li>
  <li>Column</li>
  <li>D</li>
  <li>E</li>
  <li>F</li>
  <li>G</li>
  <li>Hello</li>
  <li>I</li>
  <li>J</li>
  <li>K</li>
  <li>L</li>
  <li>M</li>
  <li>N</li>
  <li>On</li>
  <li>P</li>
  <li>Q</li>
  <li>R</li>
  <li>S</li>
  <li>Testing</li>
  <li>U</li>
  <li>V</li>
  <li>World</li>
  <li>X</li>
  <li>Y</li>
  <li>Zend</li>
</ul>
```

- use a pseudo spanning so many rows . offset it from the grid

```css
ol {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(0em, max-content));
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 1em;
  gap: 5px
}

ol:before {
  content: '';
  grid-column: -1;
  width: 0;
  grid-row: 1 /7;  /*6 rows */
}

li {
  background: silver;
  padding: 0.15em;
  margin: 0;
}

li:first-letter {
  color:tomato; /*ketchup*/
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li>A</li>
  <li>B</li>
  <li>Column</li>
  <li>D</li>
  <li>E</li>
  <li>F</li>
  <li>G</li>
  <li>Hello</li>
  <li>I</li>
  <li>J</li>
  <li>K</li>
  <li>L</li>
  <li>M</li>
  <li>N</li>
  <li>On</li>
  <li>P</li>
  <li>Q</li>
  <li>R</li>
  <li>S</li>
  <li>Testing</li>
  <li>U</li>
  <li>V</li>
  <li>World</li>
  <li>X</li>
  <li>Y</li>
  <li>Zend</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: Thanks! This served me better than the accepted answer cause it makes the elements in the columns match in height

Comment: Is there a way to make it display alphabetically from top to bottom instead of left to right?

Comment: @Dex With grid ? Yes, but you need to define either an height or a numbers of row , here 3 rows would do : https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/gOKgONa

Answer (score 20):

I like the solution for modern browsers, but the bullets are missing, so I add it a little trick:

http://jsfiddle.net/HP85j/419/

```
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    columns: 2;
    -webkit-columns: 2;
    -moz-columns: 2;
}


li:before {
  content: "• ";
}
```

[image]

Comment: Here we can change the color of the items without change the color of the bullet http://jsfiddle.net/HP85j/444/

Comment: I think `list-style-position: inside;` is a better solution for the bullets to show up properly.

Answer (score 15):

Here's a possible solution:

Snippet:

```css
ul {
  width: 760px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
}
li {
  line-height: 1.5em;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
  float: left;
  display: inline;
}
#double li {
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<ul id="double">
  <li>first</li>
  <li>second</li>
  <li>third</li>
  <li>fourth</li>
</ul>
```

And it is done.
For 3 columns use `li` width as 33%, for 4 columns use 25% and so on.

Answer (score 7):

This is the simplest way to do it. CSS only.

1. add width to the ul element.
2. add display:inline-block and width of the new column (should be less than half of the ul width).

```css
ul.list {
  width: 300px;  
}

ul.list li{
  display:inline-block;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="list">
    <li>A</li>
    <li>B</li>
    <li>C</li>
    <li>D</li>
    <li>E</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Add some explanation with answer for how this answer help OP in fixing current issue

Answer (score 6):

This can be achieved using column-count css property on parent div,

like

```
 column-count:2;
```

check this out for more details.

[How to make floating DIV list appear in columns, not rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5484215/how-to-make-floating-div-list-appear-in-columns-not-rows)

Comment: `column-count` will not display the items in the correct order. For example, the desired display in the first line is `A B` (the second element should be appended on the right), but if you use `column-count` it will be `A E`.

Answer (score 6):

You can use **CSS only** to set two columns or more

> A E
>
> B
>
> C
>
> D

```
 <ul class="columns">
    <li>A</li>
    <li>B</li>
    <li>C</li>
    <li>D</li>
    <li>E</li>
</ul>

ul.columns  {
   -webkit-columns: 60px 2;
   -moz-columns: 60px 2;
    columns: 60px 2;
   -moz-column-fill: auto;
   column-fill: auto;
 }
```

Answer (score 5):

Assuming that a multi-column layout may work well with a centered layout, `justify` a `grid` layout with a horizontal `gap`.

```css
p {
  text-align: justify;
}

ul {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, auto);
  justify-content: space-around;
  gap: 0 3em;
  text-transform: capitalize;
}
```

```html
<p>In publishing and graphic design, Lorem ipsum is a placeholder text commonly used to demonstrate the visual form of a document or a typeface without relying on meaningful content. Lorem ipsum may be used as a placeholder before final copy is available.</p>
<ul>
  <li>one</li>
  <li>two</li>
  <li>three</li>
  <li>four</li>
  <li>five</li>
  <li>six</li>
  <li>seven</li>
  <li>eight</li>
  <li>nine</li>
  <li>ten</li>
</ul>
<p>In publishing and graphic design, Lorem ipsum is a placeholder text commonly used to demonstrate the visual form of a document or a typeface without relying on meaningful content. Lorem ipsum may be used as a placeholder before final copy is available.</p>
```

Answer (score 2):

more one answer after a few years!

**in this article:** http://csswizardry.com/2010/02/mutiple-column-lists-using-one-ul/

HTML:

```
<ul id="double"> <!-- Alter ID accordingly -->
  <li>CSS</li>
  <li>XHTML</li>
  <li>Semantics</li>
  <li>Accessibility</li>
  <li>Usability</li>
  <li>Web Standards</li>
  <li>PHP</li>
  <li>Typography</li>
  <li>Grids</li>
  <li>CSS3</li>
  <li>HTML5</li>
  <li>UI</li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
ul{
  width:760px;
  margin-bottom:20px;
  overflow:hidden;
  border-top:1px solid #ccc;
}
li{
  line-height:1.5em;
  border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;
  float:left;
  display:inline;
}
#double li  { width:50%;}
#triple li  { width:33.333%; }
#quad li    { width:25%; }
#six li     { width:16.666%; }
```

Answer (score 1):

In `updateColumns()` need `if (column >= columns.length)` rather than `if (column > columns.length)` to list all elements (C is skipped for example) so:

```
function updateColumns(){
    column = 0;
    columnItems.each(function(idx, el){
        if (column >= columns.length){
            column = 0;
        }
        console.log(column, el, idx);
        $(columns.get(column)).append(el);
        column += 1;
    });
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/e2vH9/1/

Answer (score 1):

You can do this really easily with the [jQuery-Columns Plugin](http://github.com/fzondlo/jquery-columns) for example to split a ul with a class of .mylist you would do

```
$('.mylist').cols(2);
```

Here's a [live example on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EebVF/5)

I like this better than with CSS because with the CSS solution not everything aligns vertically to the top.

Comment: Interesting, but it actually breaks down the `<ul>` list in multiple lists... That could complicate other things.

Comment: This was actually the solution i was after thanks, to the downvoter this answer is valid if you read the OP's question and there was no need to DV.

Answer (score 1):

With Bootstrap... This answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/23005046/1128742) got me pointed towards this solution:

```
<ul class="list-unstyled row">
   <li class="col-xs-6">Item 1</li>
   <li class="col-xs-6">Item 2</li>
   <li class="col-xs-6">Item 3</li>
</ul>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/patrickbad767/472r0ynf/

Answer (score 1):

The legacy solution in the top answer didn't work for me because I wanted to affect multiple lists on the page and the answer assumes a single list plus it uses a fair bit of global state. In this case I wanted to alter every list inside a `<section class="list-content">`:

```
const columns = 2;
$("section.list-content").each(function (index, element) {
    let section = $(element);
    let items = section.find("ul li").detach();
    section.find("ul").detach();
    for (let i = 0; i < columns; i++) {
        section.append("<ul></ul>");
    }
    let lists = section.find("ul");
    for (let i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
        lists.get(i % columns).append(items[i]);
    }
});
```

Comment: how is it possible for instance generate two columns, one just contains the tile and the other an unordered list?

Comment: Not quite sure what you mean. If you have a series of items with titles, you could put them in a single list going title, item, title, item and then this should work for you.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me.
is the best solution because the cells in a row have the same height without taking care of the content

```css
ul {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr); 
  list-style-position: inside;
  list-style-type: none;
}
li {  border: solid 1px; }
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>asdasd asdad asdasd asdasd adasdasdasd adasdadadada adadas dasdadasdasd asd aA</li>
  <li>B</li>
  <li>C</li>
  <li>D</li>
  <li>E</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Though I found Gabriel answer to work to a degree i did find the following when trying to order the list vertically (first ul A-D and second ul E-G):

- When the ul had an even number of li's in it, it was not evenly spreading it across the ul's
- using the data-column in the ul didn't seem to work very well, I had to put 4 for 3 columns and even then it was still only spreading the li's into 2 of the ul generated by the JS

I have revised the JQuery so the above hopefully doesn't happen.

```js
(function ($) {
    var initialContainer = $('.customcolumns'),
        columnItems = $('.customcolumns li'),
        columns = null,
        column = 0;
    function updateColumns() {
        column = 0;
        columnItems.each(function (idx, el) {
            if ($(columns.get(column)).find('li').length >= (columnItems.length / initialContainer.data('columns'))) {
                column += 1;
            }
            $(columns.get(column)).append(el);
        });
    }
    function setupColumns() {
        columnItems.detach();
        while (column++ < initialContainer.data('columns')) {
            initialContainer.clone().insertBefore(initialContainer);
            column++;
        }
        columns = $('.customcolumns');
        updateColumns();
    }

    $(setupColumns);
})(jQuery);
```

```css
.customcolumns {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  margin-right: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <ul class="customcolumns" data-columns="3">
    <li>A</li>
    <li>B</li>
    <li>C</li>
    <li>D</li>
    <li>E</li>
    <li>F</li>
    <li>G</li>
    <li>H</li>
    <li>I</li>
    <li>J</li>
    <li>K</li>
    <li>L</li>
    <li>M</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an easy way to make a multiple column list using nothing more than simple CSS.  The style tags can obviously be put into a CSS if desired.

```
<p>Materials List</p>
<ul style="display: inline-block; float: left">
    <u>Item Description<u>
    <li>1/2" x 4' wood dowel</li>
    <li>1/2" x 12"  PVC pipe</li>
    <li>1/2" PVC pipe end cap</li>
    <li>7/16" x 3" light duty expansion spring</li>
    <li>6" plastic zip ties</li>
    <li>Light weight antenna</li>
</ul>
<div style="display: inline-block; margin-left: 1em">
    <u>Qty</u>
    <div style="text-indent: 0.5em">3</div>
    <div style="text-indent: 0.5em">1</div>
    <div style="text-indent: 0.5em">1</div>
    <div style="text-indent: 0.5em">2</div>
    <div style="text-indent: 0.5em">8</div>
    <div style="text-indent: 0.5em">1</div>
</div>
<p></p>
```

Answer (score -1):

Thisd was a perfect solution for me, looking it for years:

http://css-tricks.com/forums/topic/two-column-unordered-list/

Comment: _"Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline"_ - http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: No need -- it is the link/reference for the code used by `Abdul` in his answer, identical to even the width and ID used.