# Bootstrap 3 Multi-column within a single ul not floating properly

Tags: list, css-float, twitter-bootstrap-3, multiple-columns

I have been encountering problems like this on the current bootstrap 3 for a while now. I have managed to fix them in the past in one way or another but have no clue of how to fix it this time.

I need to create two columns out of one `ul` by alternating a `pull-left` & `pull-right` on list items. What am I doing wrong?

http://bootply.com/92446

Comment: I know that including rows in my markup should fix my issue but I would love to not break the list and keep having a single one.

Answer (score 157):

You should try using the [Grid Template](http://getbootstrap.com/examples/grid/).

Here's what I've used for a two Column Layout of a `<ul>`

```
<ul class="list-group row">
     <li class="list-group-item col-xs-6">Row1</li>
     <li class="list-group-item col-xs-6">Row2</li>
     <li class="list-group-item col-xs-6">Row3</li>
     <li class="list-group-item col-xs-6">Row4</li>
     <li class="list-group-item col-xs-6">Row5</li>
</ul>
```

This worked for me.

Comment: This is one of the most elegant solutions I have stumbled across on SO. Love It!

Comment: What a beauty... on top of giving me 2 columns I wanted, it neatly laid them out using the bootstrap css classes. Thanks

Comment: this one is neat.changing col-xs-6 to col-sm-6 make it more responsive.

Comment: Excellent solution! I advise on using `list-unstyled` instead of `list-group` to prevent default `ul` styling. And to prevent default styling all together, one can also get rid of `list-group-item`

Comment: Doesn't work on IE (<=11) with bootstrap 4, probably because bootstrap 4 is using Flexbox.

Comment: Actually it works on IE with BS4 if you set a fixed `height` on the UL. Setting a `max-height` is not enough :(

Comment: So cool! I tried adding <div class="row>...  with columns inside the list-group-item (where "RowN" is above) and it works like a charm.

Answer (score 12):

Thanks, `Varun Rathore`. It works perfectly!

For those who want graceful collapse from 4 items per row to 2 items per row depending on [the screen width](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-options):

```
<ul class="list-group row">
    <li class="list-group-item col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3">Cell_1</li>
    <li class="list-group-item col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3">Cell_2</li>
    <li class="list-group-item col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3">Cell_3</li>
    <li class="list-group-item col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3">Cell_4</li>
    <li class="list-group-item col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3">Cell_5</li>
    <li class="list-group-item col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3">Cell_6</li>
    <li class="list-group-item col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3">Cell_7</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 8):

you are thinking too much... Take a look at this [i think this is what you wanted - if not let me know]

http://www.bootply.com/118886

css

```
.even{background: red; color:white;}
.odd{background: darkred; color:white;}
```

html

```
<div class="container">
  <ul class="list-unstyled">
    <li class="col-md-6 odd">Dumby Content</li>
    <li class="col-md-6 odd">Dumby Content</li>
    <li class="col-md-6 even">Dumby Content</li>
    <li class="col-md-6 even">Dumby Content</li>
    <li class="col-md-6 odd">Dumby Content</li>
    <li class="col-md-6 odd">Dumby Content</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```