# How to display the list in a vertical way order using css

Tags: html, css

Trying to achieve to display the order of my lists in a vertical order.

I have 6 lists, i need to display that the first three should display on the left side and remaining on the right side.

Expected output :

```
a d
b e
c f
```

Current Output:

```
a b
c d
e f
```

HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li class="list">
        <a>a</a>
        <ul>
            <li>1</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="list">
        <a>b</a>
        <ul>
            <li>2</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="list">
        <a>c</a>
        <ul>
            <li>3</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="list">
        <a>d</a>
        <ul>
            <li>4</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="list">
        <a>e</a>
        <ul>
            <li>5</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="list">
        <a>f</a>
        <ul>
            <li>6</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I have attached what I have tried:
[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/wk30hf77/)

And it should support IE8

Comment: Can you amend them HTML at all, ir is that fixed?

Comment: @LDJ : Column-count works, but it is not supporting internet explorer 8

Comment: To support all browsers you should change your html, CSS/JS solutions will most likely have compatibility issues with IE 6/7/8

Comment: @Aramil Rey Can you Please help me out

Comment: I don't think the other answers actually get the desired output like you want.  When I tried to run the code, I didn't get the expected output like you wanted it.  This sounds like a job for Flexbox... So I have a partially working solution so far: http://jsfiddle.net/kgnv2zdw/2/.  The HTML change includes adding two list items containing one list each, which displays these two items side-by-side.  Is this going in the right direction or did I miss something completely?

Answer (score 2):

Try using

```
ul {
  column-count: 2;
}
```

Comment: @R Mugabe : It works, but not working for IE8, any alternate

Comment: Hmmm that's weird.  `column-count: 2` doesn't produce the expected output for me.  Perhaps attach a working fiddle?

Answer (score 0):

Following this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/24924657/2983435, made some adjustments to your CSS:

```
ul {
    list-style-type: disc;
    columns: 2;
    -webkit-columns: 2;
    -moz-columns: 2;
    list-style-position: inside;
}
.list{
    border:1px solid red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
ul {
   list-style:none;
    -webkit-columns: 2;
   }
.list{
    border:1px solid red;
}
```

only `-webkit-columns: 2;` is mostly required for vertical order list items

Comment: It should support IE8

Answer (score 0):

**Unfortunately, the biggest blocker to any solution given to you (i.e. `column` and `flexbox` ) is that you need the solution to be working on IE8.** There is no silver bullet when trying to support browsers that old unfortunately.

I've provided some CSS for you to add a flexbox solution for more current browsers ([Demo](http://codepen.io/BenCodeZen/pen/avvYaQ)), but you'll need to build in a fallback for IE8 that uses either a `display: block` or `display: table` since Flexbox is not supported on IE9 or IE8.

```css
ul {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -webkit-flex-direction: column;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
  -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  height: 150px;
}

li {
  height: 50px;
}
```

Hope that helps a little bit.