# Break html List into another column

Tags: html, css, list, css-multicolumn-layout

I have a html list which is too long for my container and i want to break it and show the extra items in another column. But when i use columns in css it divides the list evenly. Like if i have 12 items then 6-6 in each column. But i don't want to do this. Instead i want it to show only the extra items in the other column.

In the following picture i want to show the items from 9 to 12 in another column.

Please Help.

**Css**

```
.subMenuHolder{
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 100%;
}

.subMenu{
  border: 1px #00f solid;
  margin-left: 20px;
  list-style: inside decimal;
  padding: 30px 30px;
  width: 500px;
  height: 350px;
  -webkit-columns: 250px;
  -moz-columns: 250px;
  columns: 250px;
  -webkit-column-gap: 2em;
  -moz-column-gap: 2em;
  column-gap: 2em; 
}

.categoryMenu1{
  background: url(/theme/images/pictures/potato-onion1.png) no-repeat;
  background-size: 350px 200px;
  background-position: bottom right;
  background-color: #f2f9fd;
}

.subMenu li{
  border: 1px #f00 solid;
  padding: 5px 0px;
  text-transform: none;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #757575;
  -webkit-column-break-inside: avoid;
  page-break-inside: avoid;
  break-inside: avoid;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<ul class="subMenu categoryMenu1">
  <a class="sub-heading">Category 2</a>
  <li><a href="" data-title="Price- ₹15/kg">Cabbage</a></li>
  <li><a href="" data-title="Price- ₹15/kg">Carrot</a></li>
  <li><a href="" data-title="Price- ₹15/kg">Reddish</a></li>
  <li><a href="" data-title="Price- ₹15/kg">Peas</a></li>
  <li><a href="" data-title="Price- ₹15/kg">French Beans</a></li>
  <li><a href="" data-title="Price- ₹15/kg">Jackfruit</a></li>
  <li><a href="" data-title="Price- ₹15/kg">Tori</a></li>
  <li><a href="" data-title="Price- ₹15/kg">Sweet corn</a></li>
  <li><a href="" data-title="Price- ₹15/kg">Broccoli</a></li>
  <li><a href="" data-title="Price- ₹15/kg">Cucumber</a></li>
  <li><a href="" data-title="Price- ₹15/kg">Sem</a></li>
  <li><a href="" data-title="Price- ₹15/kg">Capsicum (Green)</a></li>
</ul>
```

Refer to this Image Please

[image]

As you can see in the image the 9 to 12 list items are out of the box. I am unable to bring it inside the box.

Comment: Please share the relevant extract(s) from your code code, highlighting what you have tried so far.

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. `ul` can only have `li` as direct children.

Comment: Ok.. That is not relevant to my question. Removing it will not solve my query.

Answer (score 0):

You were using the columns property wrong.

You had:

```
.subMenu{
...
 columns: 250px;
...
}
```

This property is not looking for the size of a column, it's looking to see how many columns should be generated (as well as other properties: [w3 CSS3 Columns Property](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_columns.asp))

So, when you change this property to "2" (or however many desired columns), I believe we get your intended result:

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/q611kjym/1/)

Side note: in your question you said it was your desire to have 9 rows in the first column and the remainder in the second.  I could not find a "column" specific way to do this, so as a hack I adjusted the height of the container.  Please see the CSS in the fiddle.

Finally, in the link provided by @AhmetEmre90, there is an IE hack - as older versions of IE won't style this property.  I'm including the link and the IE hack for posterity.

Code by: @Gabriel: [SO- How to display an unordered list in two columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14745297/how-to-display-an-unordered-list-in-two-columns/14745429#14745429)

**HTML**

```
<div>
    <ul class="columns" data-columns="2">
        <li>A</li>
        <li>B</li>
        <li>C</li>
        <li>D</li>
        <li>E</li>
        <li>F</li>
        <li>G</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
(function($){
    var initialContainer = $('.columns'),
        columnItems = $('.columns li'),
        columns = null,
        column = 1; // account for initial column
    function updateColumns(){
        column = 0;
        columnItems.each(function(idx, el){
            if (idx !== 0 && idx > (columnItems.length / columns.length) + (column * idx)){
                column += 1;
            }
            $(columns.get(column)).append(el);
        });
    }
    function setupColumns(){
        columnItems.detach();
        while (column++ < initialContainer.data('columns')){
            initialContainer.clone().insertBefore(initialContainer);
            column++;
        }
        columns = $('.columns');
    }

    $(function(){
        setupColumns();
        updateColumns();
    });
})(jQuery);
```

**CSS**

```
.columns{
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    margin-right: 20px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the information supplied it looks like the container isn't wide enough to hold the columns **including the gap** and the height needs to be calculated to ensure that the columns break at the right point.

Then the columns need to be *unbalanced* with `column-fill: auto;`

[**Codepen Demo**](http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/dMXGwQ)

```css
.subMenu {
  border: 1px #00f solid;
  margin-left: 20px;
  list-style: inside decimal;
  width: 500px;
  height: 260px;
  -webkit-columns: 180px;
  -moz-columns: 180px;
  columns: 180px;
  -webkit-column-gap: 20px;
  -moz-column-gap: 20px;
  column-gap: 20px;
  -webkit-column-fill: auto;
  -moz-column-fill: auto;
  column-fill: auto;
}
.subMenu li {
  border: 1px #f00 solid;
  padding: 5px 0px;
  text-transform: none;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #757575;
  -webkit-column-break-inside: avoid;
  page-break-inside: avoid;
  break-inside: avoid;
}
```

```html
<ul class="subMenu categoryMenu1">
  <li><a href="" data-title="Price- ₹15/kg">Cabbage</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="" data-title="Price- ₹15/kg">Carrot</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="" data-title="Price- ₹15/kg">Reddish</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="" data-title="Price- ₹15/kg">Peas</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="" data-title="Price- ₹15/kg">French Beans</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="" data-title="Price- ₹15/kg">Jackfruit</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="" data-title="Price- ₹15/kg">Tori</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="" data-title="Price- ₹15/kg">Sweet corn</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="" data-title="Price- ₹15/kg">Broccoli</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="" data-title="Price- ₹15/kg">Cucumber</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="" data-title="Price- ₹15/kg">Sem</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="" data-title="Price- ₹15/kg">Capsicum (Green)</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

As an alternative, perhaps Flexbox.

```css
.subMenu {
  border: 1px #00f solid;
  margin-left: 20px;
  list-style: inside decimal;
  width: 500px;
  height: 260px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.subMenu li {
  border: 1px #f00 solid;
  padding: 5px 0px;
  text-transform: none;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #757575;
  width: 180px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="subMenu categoryMenu1">
  <li><a href="" data-title="Price- ₹15/kg">Cabbage</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="" data-title="Price- ₹15/kg">Carrot</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="" data-title="Price- ₹15/kg">Reddish</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="" data-title="Price- ₹15/kg">Peas</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="" data-title="Price- ₹15/kg">French Beans</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="" data-title="Price- ₹15/kg">Jackfruit</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="" data-title="Price- ₹15/kg">Tori</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="" data-title="Price- ₹15/kg">Sweet corn</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="" data-title="Price- ₹15/kg">Broccoli</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="" data-title="Price- ₹15/kg">Cucumber</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="" data-title="Price- ₹15/kg">Sem</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="" data-title="Price- ₹15/kg">Capsicum (Green)</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

To achieve an non-half/half distribution of items in the two columns, you can use a **fixed `height` value** for the `ul`. Actually you are already doing that (in the css rule for `.subMenu`), so simply adjust the `height` value in that CSS rule so it fits 8 list items as desired:

(note that I changed the `width` to better fit it into the snippet window here, which of course probably isn't necessary for the real situation)

```css
subMenuHolder{
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 100%;
}

.subMenu{
  border: 1px #00f solid;
  margin-left: 20px;
  list-style: inside decimal;
  padding: 30px 30px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 280px;
  -webkit-columns: 250px;
  -moz-columns: 250px;
  columns: 250px;
  -webkit-column-gap: 2em;
  -moz-column-gap: 2em;
  column-gap: 2em; 
}

.categoryMenu1{
  background: url(/theme/images/pictures/potato-onion1.png) no-repeat;
  background-size: 350px 200px;
  background-position: bottom right;
  background-color: #f2f9fd;
}

.subMenu li{
  border: 1px #f00 solid;
  padding: 5px 0px;
  text-transform: none;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #757575;
  -webkit-column-break-inside: avoid;
  page-break-inside: avoid;
  break-inside: avoid;
}
```

```html
<ul class="subMenu categoryMenu1">
  <a class="sub-heading">Category 2</a>
  <li><a href="" data-title="Price- ₹15/kg">Cabbage</a></li>
  <li><a href="" data-title="Price- ₹15/kg">Carrot</a></li>
  <li><a href="" data-title="Price- ₹15/kg">Reddish</a></li>
  <li><a href="" data-title="Price- ₹15/kg">Peas</a></li>
  <li><a href="" data-title="Price- ₹15/kg">French Beans</a></li>
  <li><a href="" data-title="Price- ₹15/kg">Jackfruit</a></li>
  <li><a href="" data-title="Price- ₹15/kg">Tori</a></li>
  <li><a href="" data-title="Price- ₹15/kg">Sweet corn</a></li>
  <li><a href="" data-title="Price- ₹15/kg">Broccoli</a></li>
  <li><a href="" data-title="Price- ₹15/kg">Cucumber</a></li>
  <li><a href="" data-title="Price- ₹15/kg">Sem</a></li>
  <li><a href="" data-title="Price- ₹15/kg">Capsicum (Green)</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use the `columns` property of `ul`
Check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14745429/736808) for more information.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [**it would be preferable**](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes