# Adding another column when row reaches XX

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, css-tables

I am trying to make a nice display of my array data within an element that has a certain width/height. What I want to do is that when my data reaches the bottom of the element to start a new column and continue with printing the data within that next column and so on/forth

Any help is much appreciated!

My code:

```
            <div class="repeater" ng-repeat="files in files">  {{files.name}}              
                <div class='progress-bar'>
                  <div class='percentage' ng-style="style">
                  </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Current view:

[image]

Comment: Do you know how many element you can have maximum in one column ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## HTML/CSS solution

This should be better solved by CSS than by your application logic. You could display the file names as list and adapt the approach at

[How to display an unordered list in two columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14745297/how-to-display-an-unordered-list-in-two-columns)

to display them in multiple columns.

Comment: Thnx! Works fine now :)