# how to display sub-menus in grid or horizontal if you have 20 or more than 20 submenus

Tags: html, css

i have 15 sub menus in a dropdown menu and it is list all menu's fine but the sub menus are going down so i would like to show that menus horizontal or in grid what ever so is there any way to do that. this is my style.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <style>  
        #menu ul{
            list-style:none;
        }

        #menu ul li{
            background-color:red;
            border:1px solid white;
            width:120px;
            height:35px;
            line-height:35px;
            text-align:center;
            float:left;
            position:relative;
        }
        #menu ul li a{
            text-decoration:none;
            color:white;

            display:block;
        }

        #menu ul li a:hover
            {
            background-color:gold;
        }
        #menu ul ul{
            position:absolute;
            display:none;
        }

        #menu ul li:hover > ul
        {
                display:block;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="menu">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Tutorials</a>

                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">SALES AND DISTRIBUTION</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">C-SHARP</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">SQL</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">WCF</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">ASP.NET</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">ADO.NET</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">LINQ</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">ENTITY FRAMEWORK</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">ASP.NET MVC</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">WPF</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">ABAP</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">ETL</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">SSIS</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">SSAS</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">SSRS</a></li>
                    </ul>


            </li>
            <li><a href="#">IntervieQuestions</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">ContactUs</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If you have that many sub menu items the first thing to do is think about your site structure.

Comment: Secondly, look into so-called "mega menus".

Comment: hello Pualie tq u 4ur reply soon i have seen in many websites that they are managing their sub-menus in a block when hover 4ur reference www.tutorialpoint.com

Answer (score 0):

It's not difficult to force the menu unordered list into two or more columns using CSS3 multicolumn layout features.  IE8 would still display in one column, but that's a reasonable fall-back.

```
.list-columns {
-moz-column-count: 2;
-moz-column-gap: 60px;
-webkit-column-count: 2;
-webkit-column-gap: 60px;
column-count: 2;
column-gap: 60px;
}
```

[Related Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14745297/how-to-display-an-unordered-list-in-two-columns)

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/karlikdesign/fmroxyLy/)

[Browser Support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=multicolumn)