# How to create two columns from a QuerySet in a Django template

Tags: django, django-templates

```
def get_queryset(self):
    return AnnualMean.objects.values("Site", "url")
```

With the above QuerySet from my views.py file, I can make a list of URL links appear on a page as one long column using this code:

```
{% for value in object_list %}
<ul><a href="/sites/{{value.url}}/">{{value.Site}}</a></ul>
{% endfor %}
```

It would be much better to have the list split into halves across two columns. I have spent a long time trying and looking at related forum posts. I think my difficulties might lie with with the html tags. Is there any way I can achieve what I am trying to do?

Comment: You could have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14745297/how-to-display-an-unordered-list-in-two-columns.

Comment: Thanks, although I can't see how I can go about using that html or css code in my django template

Comment: Look at django static files