# How to make category with two columns under

Tags: html, css

I want to create categories and two columns data under. Example:

```
- category1
-- item1 item2
-- item3 item4
-- item5 item6
- category2
-- item1 item2
-- item3 item4
```

My code:

**css**

```
ul{
    width:210px;
}
li{
    float:left;
    margin:0 40px 40px 0;
}
li:nth-child(even){
    margin-right:0;
}
```

**html**

```
<div>
     <span>Category</span>
     <ul>
          <li>
               <span>Test</span>
               <input type="checkbox">
          </li>
     </ul>
</div>
```

I suggested this topic: [How to display an unordered list in two columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14745297/how-to-display-an-unordered-list-in-two-columns) , but not good, because categories are in a bad position. Any solution?

Comment: can you please post the proper html with the layout issue and also the expected result as an image. The HTML provided has nothing much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could achieve a similar effect using `flexbox` properties...

```css
ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width:210px;
}

li {
  flex: 1 1 50%;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span>Category</span>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <span>Test</span>
      <input type="checkbox">
    </li>
    <li>
      <span>Test 2</span>
      <input type="checkbox">
    </li>
    <li>
      <span>Test 3</span>
      <input type="checkbox">
    </li>
    <li>
      <span>Test 4</span>
      <input type="checkbox">
    </li>
    <li>
      <span>Test 5</span>
      <input type="checkbox">
    </li>
    <li>
      <span>Test 6</span>
      <input type="checkbox">
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using `flexbox` with `flex-wrap:wrap;`

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box; 
  font-family: Open Sans;
}

html, body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

.cat-list {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 1rem;
}

.cat-list li {
  margin-bottom: 0.5rem;
  font-size: 20px;
  flex: 1 0 50%;
}

.flex-list {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.cat-container {
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

.cat-header {
  margin: 0;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #999;
  padding: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="cat-container">
  <h4 class="cat-header">Category 1</h4>
  <ul class="cat-list flex-list">
    <li>
      <span>Item 1</span>
      <input type="checkbox" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <span>Item 2</span>
      <input type="checkbox" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <span>Item 3</span>
      <input type="checkbox" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <span>Item 4</span>
      <input type="checkbox" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <span>Item 5</span>
      <input type="checkbox" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <span>Item 6</span>
      <input type="checkbox" />
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="cat-container">
  <h4 class="cat-header">Category 2</h4>
  <ul class="cat-list flex-list">
    <li>
      <span>Item 1</span>
      <input type="checkbox" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <span>Item 2</span>
      <input type="checkbox" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <span>Item 3</span>
      <input type="checkbox" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <span>Item 4</span>
      <input type="checkbox" />
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```