# How to align every two <li> next to each other

Tags: html, css

I am trying to align every two **li** elements side by side (Like : 0-9, A-B, C-D, ...). Currently, it is aligned one-by-one.

```
<ul>
    <li class="alphabetRow"><a href="#" id="alpha_1" class="alphabet active" >0-9</a></li>
    <li class="alphabetRow"><a href="#" id="alpha_2" class="alphabet" >A</a></li>
    <li class="alphabetRow"><a href="#" id="alpha_3" class="alphabet" >B</a></li>
    <li class="alphabetRow"><a href="#" id="alpha_4" class="alphabet" >C</a></li>
    <li class="alphabetRow"><a href="#" id="alpha_5" class="alphabet" >D</a></li>
    <li class="alphabetRow"><a href="#" id="alpha_6" class="alphabet" >E</a></li>
    <li class="alphabetRow"><a href="#" id="alpha_7" class="alphabet" >F</a></li>
    <li class="alphabetRow"><a href="#" id="alpha_8" class="alphabet" >G</a></li>
    <li class="alphabetRow"><a href="#" id="alpha_9" class="alphabet" >H</a></li>
    <li class="alphabetRow"><a href="#" id="alpha_10" class="alphabet" >I</a></li>
    <li class="alphabetRow"><a href="#" id="alpha_11" class="alphabet" >J</a></li>
    <li class="alphabetRow"><a href="#" id="alpha_12" class="alphabet" >K</a></li>
    <li class="alphabetRow"><a href="#" id="alpha_13" class="alphabet" >L</a></li>
    <li class="alphabetRow"><a href="#" id="alpha_14" class="alphabet" >M</a></li>
    <li class="alphabetRow"><a href="#" id="alpha_15" class="alphabet" >N</a></li>
    <li class="alphabetRow"><a href="#" id="alpha_16" class="alphabet" >O</a></li>
    <li class="alphabetRow"><a href="#" id="alpha_17" class="alphabet" >P</a></li>
    <li class="alphabetRow"><a href="#" id="alpha_18" class="alphabet" >Q</a></li>
    <li class="alphabetRow"><a href="#" id="alpha_19" class="alphabet" >R</a></li>
    <li class="alphabetRow"><a href="#" id="alpha_20" class="alphabet" >S</a></li>
    <li class="alphabetRow"><a href="#" id="alpha_21" class="alphabet" >T</a></li>
    <li class="alphabetRow"><a href="#" id="alpha_22" class="alphabet" >U</a></li>
    <li class="alphabetRow"><a href="#" id="alpha_23" class="alphabet" >V</a></li>
    <li class="alphabetRow"><a href="#" id="alpha_24" class="alphabet" >W</a></li>
    <li class="alphabetRow"><a href="#" id="alpha_25" class="alphabet" >X</a></li>
    <li class="alphabetRow"><a href="#" id="alpha_26" class="alphabet" >Y</a></li>
    <li class="alphabetRow"><a href="#" id="alpha_27" class="alphabet" >Z</a></li>
  </ul>
```

**Fiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/g8jzgzev/1/

Comment: You want to the outut to be like this 
0-9,
A-B,
C-D

after every two li you want new line ??

Comment: You could make `<li>` with A-B, unlike you did each alphabet with individual character.

Comment: @Krishna9960, yes.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to display an unordered list in two columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14745297/how-to-display-an-unordered-list-in-two-columns)

Answer (score 3):

You mean like this. https://jsfiddle.net/g8jzgzev/4/

```
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  overflow: hidden;
}
li {
  float: left;
}
li:nth-child(2n) {
  clear: left;
}
```

Float them and clear every third one.

Comment: thanks for reply. Is it possible to put hyphen(-) between AB ad CD.. (like A-B, C-D..)?

Answer (score 1):

do you want like this

```css
/*.col-sm-6{
  width:50%;
  float:left;
}
*/
ul li{
  width:50%;
  float:left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
    <li class="alphabetRow"><a href="#" id="alpha_1" class="alphabet active" >0-9</a></li>
    <li class="alphabetRow"><a href="#" id="alpha_2" class="alphabet" >A</a></li>
    <li class="alphabetRow"><a href="#" id="alpha_3" class="alphabet" >B</a></li>
    <li class="alphabetRow"><a href="#" id="alpha_4" class="alphabet" >C</a></li>
    <li class="alphabetRow"><a href="#" id="alpha_5" class="alphabet" >D</a></li>
    <li class="alphabetRow"><a href="#" id="alpha_6" class="alphabet" >E</a></li>
    <li class="alphabetRow"><a href="#" id="alpha_7" class="alphabet" >F</a></li>
    <li class="alphabetRow"><a href="#" id="alpha_8" class="alphabet" >G</a></li>
    <li class="alphabetRow"><a href="#" id="alpha_9" class="alphabet" >H</a></li>
    <li class="alphabetRow"><a href="#" id="alpha_10" class="alphabet" >I</a></li>
    <li class="alphabetRow"><a href="#" id="alpha_11" class="alphabet" >J</a></li>
    <li class="alphabetRow"><a href="#" id="alpha_12" class="alphabet" >K</a></li>
    <li class="alphabetRow"><a href="#" id="alpha_13" class="alphabet" >L</a></li>
    <li class="alphabetRow"><a href="#" id="alpha_14" class="alphabet" >M</a></li>
    <li class="alphabetRow"><a href="#" id="alpha_15" class="alphabet" >N</a></li>
    <li class="alphabetRow"><a href="#" id="alpha_16" class="alphabet" >O</a></li>
    <li class="alphabetRow"><a href="#" id="alpha_17" class="alphabet" >P</a></li>
    <li class="alphabetRow"><a href="#" id="alpha_18" class="alphabet" >Q</a></li>
    <li class="alphabetRow"><a href="#" id="alpha_19" class="alphabet" >R</a></li>
    <li class="alphabetRow"><a href="#" id="alpha_20" class="alphabet" >S</a></li>
    <li class="alphabetRow"><a href="#" id="alpha_21" class="alphabet" >T</a></li>
    <li class="alphabetRow"><a href="#" id="alpha_22" class="alphabet" >U</a></li>
    <li class="alphabetRow"><a href="#" id="alpha_23" class="alphabet" >V</a></li>
    <li class="alphabetRow"><a href="#" id="alpha_24" class="alphabet" >W</a></li>
    <li class="alphabetRow"><a href="#" id="alpha_25" class="alphabet" >X</a></li>
    <li class="alphabetRow"><a href="#" id="alpha_26" class="alphabet" >Y</a></li>
    <li class="alphabetRow"><a href="#" id="alpha_27" class="alphabet" >Z</a></li>
  </ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to align every two li elements side by side, I guess that you're looking for a [multi column list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14745297/how-to-display-an-unordered-list-in-two-columns).

Answer (score 1):

Use following CSS for li tag

```css
ul li{
  width:50%;
  float:left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
    <li class="alphabetRow"><a href="#" id="alpha_1" class="alphabet active" >0-9</a></li>
    <li class="alphabetRow"><a href="#" id="alpha_2" class="alphabet" >A</a></li>
    <li class="alphabetRow"><a href="#" id="alpha_3" class="alphabet" >B</a></li>
    <li class="alphabetRow"><a href="#" id="alpha_4" class="alphabet" >C</a></li>
    <li class="alphabetRow"><a href="#" id="alpha_5" class="alphabet" >D</a></li>
    <li class="alphabetRow"><a href="#" id="alpha_6" class="alphabet" >E</a></li>
    <li class="alphabetRow"><a href="#" id="alpha_7" class="alphabet" >F</a></li>
    <li class="alphabetRow"><a href="#" id="alpha_8" class="alphabet" >G</a></li>
    <li class="alphabetRow"><a href="#" id="alpha_9" class="alphabet" >H</a></li>
    <li class="alphabetRow"><a href="#" id="alpha_10" class="alphabet" >I</a></li>
    <li class="alphabetRow"><a href="#" id="alpha_11" class="alphabet" >J</a></li>
    <li class="alphabetRow"><a href="#" id="alpha_12" class="alphabet" >K</a></li>
    <li class="alphabetRow"><a href="#" id="alpha_13" class="alphabet" >L</a></li>
    <li class="alphabetRow"><a href="#" id="alpha_14" class="alphabet" >M</a></li>
    <li class="alphabetRow"><a href="#" id="alpha_15" class="alphabet" >N</a></li>
    <li class="alphabetRow"><a href="#" id="alpha_16" class="alphabet" >O</a></li>
    <li class="alphabetRow"><a href="#" id="alpha_17" class="alphabet" >P</a></li>
    <li class="alphabetRow"><a href="#" id="alpha_18" class="alphabet" >Q</a></li>
    <li class="alphabetRow"><a href="#" id="alpha_19" class="alphabet" >R</a></li>
    <li class="alphabetRow"><a href="#" id="alpha_20" class="alphabet" >S</a></li>
    <li class="alphabetRow"><a href="#" id="alpha_21" class="alphabet" >T</a></li>
    <li class="alphabetRow"><a href="#" id="alpha_22" class="alphabet" >U</a></li>
    <li class="alphabetRow"><a href="#" id="alpha_23" class="alphabet" >V</a></li>
    <li class="alphabetRow"><a href="#" id="alpha_24" class="alphabet" >W</a></li>
    <li class="alphabetRow"><a href="#" id="alpha_25" class="alphabet" >X</a></li>
    <li class="alphabetRow"><a href="#" id="alpha_26" class="alphabet" >Y</a></li>
    <li class="alphabetRow"><a href="#" id="alpha_27" class="alphabet" >Z</a></li>
  </ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's the updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Manoj1991/g8jzgzev/10/),
Add the CSS

```
ul {
  list-style-type: none;

}
ul li{
   display: inline;
   float:left;
}

li:nth-child(2n) {   
  clear: left; 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. Is it possible to put hyphen(-) between AB ad CD.. (like A-B, C-D..)?

Comment: Good CSS Way :)

Comment: I have posted a Jquery way Solution...But i would suggest go @Manoj's Way..Performance will be good.

Comment: Here's updated fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/Manoj1991/g8jzgzev/17/  @NNR

Answer (score 0):

```
$('li').each(function(index) {
    if(index%2 == 0)
       $(this).after("<br>");   
});

//CSS

ul {
  list-style-type: none;

}
li{
 display: inline-block;
 float: left;
}
```

Jquery Way working fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/g8jzgzev/14/

Answer (score 0):

Use pseudo class even

```
li:nth-child(even) {
float:left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just go through this.
You can use CSS3 :nth-child() Selector to achieve this thing.

Specify a content as '-' for every `<li>` element after the current content whose index is a multiple of 2:
 for that the code is `li:nth-child(2n):after`

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  overflow: hidden;
}
li {
  float: left;
}
li:nth-child(2n) {
  clear: left;
  content:
}
li:nth-child(2n):after {
  content: "–";
  }
```

```html
<ul>
    <li class="alphabetRow"><a href="#" id="alpha_1" class="alphabet active" >0-9</a></li>
    <li class="alphabetRow"><a href="#" id="alpha_2" class="alphabet" >A</a></li>
    <li class="alphabetRow"><a href="#" id="alpha_3" class="alphabet" >B</a></li>
    <li class="alphabetRow"><a href="#" id="alpha_4" class="alphabet" >C</a></li>
    <li class="alphabetRow"><a href="#" id="alpha_5" class="alphabet" >D</a></li>
    <li class="alphabetRow"><a href="#" id="alpha_6" class="alphabet" >E</a></li>
    <li class="alphabetRow"><a href="#" id="alpha_7" class="alphabet" >F</a></li>
    <li class="alphabetRow"><a href="#" id="alpha_8" class="alphabet" >G</a></li>
    <li class="alphabetRow"><a href="#" id="alpha_9" class="alphabet" >H</a></li>
    <li class="alphabetRow"><a href="#" id="alpha_10" class="alphabet" >I</a></li>
    <li class="alphabetRow"><a href="#" id="alpha_11" class="alphabet" >J</a></li>
    <li class="alphabetRow"><a href="#" id="alpha_12" class="alphabet" >K</a></li>
    <li class="alphabetRow"><a href="#" id="alpha_13" class="alphabet" >L</a></li>
    <li class="alphabetRow"><a href="#" id="alpha_14" class="alphabet" >M</a></li>
    <li class="alphabetRow"><a href="#" id="alpha_15" class="alphabet" >N</a></li>
    <li class="alphabetRow"><a href="#" id="alpha_16" class="alphabet" >O</a></li>
    <li class="alphabetRow"><a href="#" id="alpha_17" class="alphabet" >P</a></li>
    <li class="alphabetRow"><a href="#" id="alpha_18" class="alphabet" >Q</a></li>
    <li class="alphabetRow"><a href="#" id="alpha_19" class="alphabet" >R</a></li>
    <li class="alphabetRow"><a href="#" id="alpha_20" class="alphabet" >S</a></li>
    <li class="alphabetRow"><a href="#" id="alpha_21" class="alphabet" >T</a></li>
    <li class="alphabetRow"><a href="#" id="alpha_22" class="alphabet" >U</a></li>
    <li class="alphabetRow"><a href="#" id="alpha_23" class="alphabet" >V</a></li>
    <li class="alphabetRow"><a href="#" id="alpha_24" class="alphabet" >W</a></li>
    <li class="alphabetRow"><a href="#" id="alpha_25" class="alphabet" >X</a></li>
    <li class="alphabetRow"><a href="#" id="alpha_26" class="alphabet" >Y</a></li>
    <li class="alphabetRow"><a href="#" id="alpha_27" class="alphabet" >Z</a></li>
  </ul>
```

Comment: Is this is your expected output?