# Break item via CSS with fixed number?

Tags: html, css

I´ve got this list of items:

```
<div class="break-3">
<ul>
    <li>
    <div class="title">A</div>
    <div class="text"></div>
    </li>
    <li>
    <div class="title">B</div>
    <div class="text"></div>
    </li>
    <li>
    <div class="title">C</div>
    <div class="text"></div>
    </li>
    <li>
    <div class="title">D</div>
    <div class="text"></div>
    </li>
    <li>
    <div class="title">E</div>
    <div class="text"></div>
    </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

With no fixed height. Now I want with the class"break-3", that the list breaks / floats right after the 3rd element.

It should look like this:

```
A  D
B  E
C
```

How can I do that?

Thanks

Comment: .break-3 > ul > li{float:right;}
.break-3 > ul > li:nth-child(1), break-3 > ul > li:nth-child(2), break-3 > ul > li:nth-child(3) {float:left;}

Comment: This may help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14745297/how-to-display-an-unordered-list-in-two-columns

Comment: I added some more information to my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this way

```css
.break-3 {
    -webkit-columns: 100px 2; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    -moz-columns: 100px 2; /* Firefox */
    columns: 100px 2;
}
li {list-style:none;}
```

```html
<div class="break-3">
    <ul>
    <li>
    <div class="title">A</div>
    <div class="text"></div>
    </li>
    <li>
    <div class="title">B</div>
    <div class="text"></div>
    </li>
    <li>
    <div class="title">C</div>
    <div class="text"></div>
    </li>
    <li>
    <div class="title">D</div>
    <div class="text"></div>
    </li>
    <li>
    <div class="title">E</div>
    <div class="text"></div>
    </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thx but how do i  set the number of items where it should break?

Answer (score 0):

You can target them all

```
.break-3 > ul > li{
  YOUR CSS
}
```

Then you can target just the first 3 to tell them to not do what the others are doing

```
.break-3 > ul > li:nth-child(1),
.break-3 > ul > li:nth-child(2),
.break-3 > ul > li:nth-child(3) {
  YOUR CSS
}
```

Answer (score -1):

you can not break from third element but you can do it this way

```
ul li{
    display:inline-block;
    width:calc(50% - 4px);
}
```

Comment: That's the opposite of what he wanted