# get specific result with map

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I try to learning react.js and stuck on get specific result on map. here is the code

```
render(){
const  friends = [
 {id:1, name: 'Dave',age:50},
{id:2,name: 'Kellie',age:42},
{id:3,name: 'Max',age:12},
{id:2,name: 'Jack',age:12}
];
return(
<div>
<ul>
{friends.map(p => <li key={p.id}>{p.name}</li>)}
</ul>;
</div>
);
```

result:

*Dave

*Kellie

*Max

*Jack

how to get result like this with map?

*Dave *Kellie

*Max *Jack

and how to get result from specific range on index like this?

*Max *Jack

thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`map` isn't a react-js specific function, it's native to the javascript array - [See the MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

How you want to work out your list formatting is up to you. [One answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14745297/how-to-display-an-unordered-list-in-two-columns) suggests using css3.

Getting a specific result is as simple as using `slice` e.g. `friends.slice(2).map(...)`