# how to make the content of a div go to the next column by exceeding the height of this div

Tags: html, css

I apologize if I have not formulated the question well, I hope to make myself understood. basically I have a list of elements, these are distributed in each line. I would like that when this line is going to exceed the total size of the div, the list will continue in the space available in front.

[image]

```
<div>
  <ul>
    <li>
      1  
    </li>
    <li>
      2  
    </li>
    <li>
      3  
    </li>
    <li>
      4  
    </li>
    <li>
      5  
    </li>
    <li>
      6
    </li>      
  </ul>
</div>

div
{ 
 border: 1px solid red;
 height: 100px;
 width:300px;
}
```

how can I do it?

https://jsfiddle.net/ug0f38b1/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to display an unordered list in two columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14745297/how-to-display-an-unordered-list-in-two-columns)

Comment: You can use the `columns` module to achieve the desired effect. Check for a complete explanation on the [question link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14745429/7630248) included in the previous comment.

Comment: @ChrisTapay but I do not want to distribute my content evenly in columns. simply the last item in the other column ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm using flexbox to solve this with the direction set to `column`. You need the height of the `ul` to fill the parent container so it knows when to break.

The items are naturally distributed as the list grows.
[image]

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: 100px;
  width: 300px;
}

ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <ul>
    <li>
      1
    </li>
    <li>
      2
    </li>
    <li>
      3
    </li>
    <li>
      4
    </li>
    <li>
      5
    </li>
    <li>
      6
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fhn7516o/1/)

### Adjusting column spacing

One nice thing about using flexbox for this is that we can set the `ul` to be `inline-flex` which allows easy control over the column spacing.

[image]

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8a965zb3/1/)

Answer (score 0):

A combination of both [`columns`](https://caniuse.com/#feat=multicolumn) and `column-fill` can be used. Check the example below.

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: 100px;
  width: 300px;
  padding: 1rem;
}

ul {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
  columns: 2;
  -webkit-columns: 2;
  -moz-columns: 2;
  -webkit-column-fill: auto;
  -moz-column-fill: auto;
  column-fill: auto;
}
```

```html
<div>
      <ul>
        <li>
          1  
        </li>
        <li>
          2  
        </li>
        <li>
          3  
        </li>
        <li>
          4  
        </li>
        <li>
          5  
        </li>
        <li>
          6
        </li> 
        <li>
          7  
        </li>
        <li>
          8
        </li> 
      </ul>
    </div>
```