# How can i order colum css

Tags: html, css, sass

I'm trying to create a layout like below

I have an object like this

```
[1]
[2]
[3]
[4]
```

But when i break these column into 2 columns i have this result
https://jsfiddle.net/juh7fe8o/1/

```
[1] [3] 
[2] [4]
```

The expected result should be like this

```
[1] [2]
[3] [4]
```

How can i order these columns? All of my elements have a index that could be used

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to display an unordered list in two columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14745297/how-to-display-an-unordered-list-in-two-columns)

Comment: I think this is duplicated with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14745297/how-to-display-an-unordered-list-in-two-columns

Answer (score 0):

you may use grid instead column:

```css
ul {
  display:grid;
  grid-template-columns:repeat(2,1fr);
  gap: 20px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li>Item 3</li>
    <li>Item 4</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use flexbox:

```css
ul {
  display:flex;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
}
li {
  width:50%;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li>Item 3</li>
    <li>Item 4</li>
</ul>
```