# How can i make my ul li to create new column when the li reaches 5 contents?

Tags: html, css

This is my sample code

```css
ul li{
    list-style: none;
  }
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>LINE ONE</li> 
  <li>LINE ONE</li> 
  <li>LINE ONE</li> 
  <li>LINE ONE</li> 
  <li>LINE ONE</li> 
  <li>LINE ONE</li> 
  <li>LINE ONE</li> 
  <li>LINE ONE</li> 

  <li>LINE TWO</li> 
  <li>LINE TWO</li> 
  <li>LINE TWO</li> 
  <li>LINE TWO</li> 
  <li>LINE TWO</li> 
  <li>LINE TWO</li> 
  <li>LINE TWO</li> 
  <li>LINE TWO</li> 
</ul>
```

and this is what i am trying to achieve without using grid system.
[image]

i am not sure if there is a existing question similar to mine, if there is please leave a link because i've been trying to search it and i just dont know the right keyword for this problem. Thank you

Comment: always 2 columns or you will need 3 if it's more than 10 items ?

Comment: Is the data dynamically generated? Or it is just static HTML and CSS?

Comment: And what do you want to happen if the viewport is narrow?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14745297/how-to-display-an-unordered-list-in-two-columns

Comment: Could you say why you aren't able to use grid and which order do you want the elements to show? First 5 vertically then second 5 in second column or other way?

Comment: The OP didn't say they cant use *grid*, just not a **grid system**.

Comment: it's so sad that you are so mad for not getting a quick reply, the fact that people do sleep to rest. @AlonEitan

Comment: just 2 columns only @TemaniAfif

Comment: just static HTML and CSS only @MohammadDohadwala.

Answer (score 1):

CSS-Grid can do that. Just define a maximum of 5 rows.

```css
ul li {
  list-style: none;
}

ul {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(5, min-content);
  grid-auto-flow: column;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>4</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you for the idea Mr. Paulie_D