# How would I go about creating an unordered list that displays 2 list items per line?

Tags: html, css

I wanted to ask how I would go about achieving the results mentioned in the title?
This is different to the other answers as those answers don't use the `display: grid;` styling as mentioned in the answer below:

```
<ul class="item">
    <li class="headings">Heading 1:</li><li>Value 1 </li>
    <li class="headings">Heading 1:</li><li>Value 2</li>
    <li class="headings">Heading 3:</li>
    <li class="headings">Heading 4</li><li>Value 4</li>
    <li class="headings">Heading 5</li><li>Value 5</li></ul>
</ul>
```

I know the correct way to accomplish this would be to have a new unordered list for every 2nd list item, but for some reason the car-row outputs all the list items within a single unordered list.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14745297/how-to-display-an-unordered-list-in-two-columns

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to display an unordered list in two columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14745297/how-to-display-an-unordered-list-in-two-columns)

Comment: @JaswinderKaur no it seemed like the `display: grid;` styling mentioned below did the trick.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use display `grid`. Something like this:

```css
.item{
   display: grid;
   grid-template-columns: repeat(2, minmax(0, 1fr));
}
```

```html
<ul class="item">
    <li class="headings">Heading 1:</li>
    <li>Value 1</li>
    <li class="headings">Heading 1:</li>
    <li>Value 2</li>
    <li class="headings">Heading 3:</li>
    <li>Value 3</li>
    <li class="headings">Heading 4</li>
    <li>Value 4</li>
    <li class="headings">Heading 5</li>
    <li>Value 5</li></ul>
</ul>
```

Or

You can change `ul` default behaviour, Something like this:

```
ul {
  columns: 2;
  -webkit-columns: 2;
  -moz-columns: 2;
}
```

Comment: thanks very much, it seems like the 'display: grid' styling did the trick!

Comment: One question I still have is how would I add a new line if the unordered list only has a heading & no value?

Comment: In your case, just add a `li` tag even with no value, this way display grid will still consider lt like a grid cell.