# Chrome printing is cutting off text between tr element for multi-column css

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

How do I prevent this behavior?

https://plnkr.co/edit/QoO2hWmXVhSCSyA4bUh4?p=preview

```
<style type="text/css">
            table {
                border-collapse: collapse;
            }

            table, th, td {
                border: 1px solid black;
            }
            @page {
                size: auto;   /* auto is the initial value */
                margin: 5mm 7mm 5mm 7mm; /* margin you want for the content */
            }

            html {
                background-color: #FFFFFF;
                margin: 0px; /* this affects the margin on the html before sending to printer */
            }
            table { page-break-inside: avoid }
            tr    { page-break-inside: avoid; page-break-after: avoid }
            thead { display: table-header-group }
            tfoot { display: table-footer-group }
            .paper {
                font-size: 11pt;
                -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact;
                -moz-column-count: 2;
                -moz-column-gap: 10px;
                -webkit-column-count: 2;
                -webkit-column-gap: 10px;
                column-count: 2;
                column-gap: 10px;
            }

            .website {
                font-size: 11pt;
                -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact;
                -moz-column-count: 2;
                -moz-column-gap: 10px;
                -webkit-column-count: 2;
                -webkit-column-gap: 10px;
                column-count: 2;
                column-gap: 10px;
            }

            .inline {
                -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact;
                display: inline-block;
                width: 100%;
            }

            .customer-color {
                -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact;
                background-color: rgba(38, 194, 129, 0.1);
            }

            .partner-color {
                -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact;
                background-color: rgba(227, 91, 90, 0.1);
            }
        </style>
```

This is my css styling. You can try printing from plunkr and will see that this occurs,
[image]
I have tried the solution from following post, [Why is Chrome cutting off text in my CSS3 multi-column layout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3322891/why-is-chrome-cutting-off-text-in-my-css3-multi-column-layout) but couldn't fix the problem. The post seems to be from 2010 so perhaps there is a new solution for 2016?

Comment: If you set margins to 0, it shouldn't be cut off.

Comment: Thank you for your response, if I set margin 0 then I will run into printing margin problem? UPDATE: I have just tested with margin 0, the problem is still occuring

Comment: Try setting output to fit to screen and margins to 0. I'm talking about the printer settings by the way, not print CSS.

Comment: I am not able to solve the problem : (

Comment: Was this ever solved? I also ran into the same problem when I added a top and bottom margin to @page and haven't been able to figure out a solution.

Comment: @huertanix this was so long ago. But as I recall, I don't think it  was solved. I ended up manually size the row to fit accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into a similar problem, and perhaps this might help. Check your CSS media queries.

Problem: 
Printing causes content at the bottom of the page to be cut off/missing.

Theory:

1. Print: print.window detects page content/size (X)
2. Force paper-page size/layout with context (X)
3. Smaller paper-page size triggers CSS media queries
4. Layout changes. In my case bootstrap's col-md-6, removed float.
5. Which elongates the page (Y)
6. Y>X ==> produces missing content

My solution was to address the @media query to maintain my expected layout.

Helpful tool:
Chrome dev tools>More tools>Rendering>Emulate CSS Media>Print

Comment: Thank you so much for the solution I'll try one day when I need to do this again!

Comment: How would one go about addressing the @media query? The print one is the only one being used and if one wants specific margins per-page rather than per html container, I don't know if there's anything that can be done here.